# Terraform: local helm not found

Tags: terraform

Here, my structure:

```
.
├── development
│   ├── inputs.tf
│   ├── main.tf
│   ├── manifests
│   ├── provider.tf
│   ├── terraform.tfstate
│   └── terraform.tfstate.backup
├── helms
│   └── zeppelin
└── modules
    └── zeppelin
```

Into `_/modules/zeppelin/main.tf`:

```
resource "helm_release" "zeppelin" {
    name       = "zeppelin"
    chart      = "../../helms/zeppelin"
    namespace  = var.namespace
}
```

As you can see, I'm trying to reach my zeppelin helm located into `../../helms/zeppelin`.

I'm getting this error message:

```
Error: path "../../helms/zeppelin" not found

  on ../modules/zeppelin/main.tf line 1, in resource "helm_release" "zeppelin":
   1: resource "helm_release" "zeppelin" {
```

My `_/development/main.tf`:

```
module "zeppelin" {
    source = "../modules/zeppelin"

    namespace = var.namespace
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: That only looks like one directory down to me? What does `../helms/zeppelin` show? Also you should consider using the interpolated path values as mentioned in https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/expressions.html#references-to-named-values

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and using `${path.module}` did the trick.

Try using `${path.module}/../../helms/zeppelin` instead

Answer (score 0):

Because you are standing on `_/development/main.tf` to call `_/modules/zeppelin/main.tf`, so your current path must be `_/development` not `_/development/zeppelin`. The mechanism here is like in bash script, you call a script, that script calls another script which executes the `pwd` command, the output should be the directory of the script you called at first.